# Angular Bootstrap - Dropdown works locally, not on server

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

On my local environment, I am loading in Angular Bootstrap UI. All seems to be working, I have a simple dropdown menu as follows:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle"><span ng-bind="conn.email"></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This shows my email address, with the dropdown which works fine.

Put this on the live server, and it fails. No dropdown appears, with nothing being logged in the console. Only my email which doesn't toggle.

As per the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown), I've also tried the method in there:

```
<li class="dropdown" dropdown>
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle><span ng-bind="conn.email"></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

This ends up not even showing anything on local or server - I assume something is up with the directive?

`UI Bootstrap: Version: 0.11.0`

Comment: I would ensure all your requests are working.  Use browser tools or fiddler to check.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had a class and directive defined:

```
<li class="dropdown" dropdown>
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle><span ng-bind="conn.email"></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

I changed this to:

```
<li dropdown>
   <a dropdown-toggle><span ng-bind="conn.email"></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

This works for both now.